# Prism and Simple Injector

Tags: mvvm, uwp, prism, simple-injector

I'm trying a simple `HelloWorld` using simple inject and prism.
[Git Source](https://github.com/rubgithub/HelloWorldPrismUWP/tree/SimpleInjector)

When application starts, this error come up

> Failed to assign to property
>   'Prism.Windows.Mvvm.ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel'. [Line: 8
>   Position: 5]"
>
> ---
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.MissingMethodException' in Prism.Windows.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' in
>   HelloWorldPrism.exe WinRT information: Failed to assign to property
>   'Prism.Windows.Mvvm.ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel'. [Line: 8
>   Position: 5] An exception of type
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   HelloWorldPrism.exe but was not handled in user code WinRT
>   information: Failed to assign to property
>   'Prism.Windows.Mvvm.ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel'. [Line: 8
>   Position: 5] Additional information: The text associated with this
>   error code could not be found. Failed to assign to property
>   'Prism.Windows.Mvvm.ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel'. [Line: 8
>   Position: 5]
>
> e.StackTrace  "   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.LoadComponent(Object
>   component, Uri resourceLocator,  ComponentResourceLocation
>   componentResourceLocation)\r\n    at
>   HelloWorldPrism.Views.MainView.InitializeComponent()\r\n    at
>   HelloWorldPrism.Views.MainView..ctor()"   string

```
<Page
    x:Class="HelloWorldPrism.Views.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:mvvm="using:Prism.Windows.Mvvm"
    mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    >
```

---

```
public MainViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
{
    _navigationService = navigationService;
}
```

---

If I add a parameterless constructor it works normal.

```
public MainViewModel()
{
}
```

---

**App.cs**

```
protected override Task OnLaunchApplicationAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    Window.Current.Activate();
    return Task.FromResult(true);
}

protected override void CreateAndConfigureContainer()
{
    Logger.Log("Creating and Configuring Container", Category.Debug, Priority.Low);
    Container = CreateContainer();
}

protected override Container CreateContainer()
{
    return new Container();
}

protected override UIElement CreateShell(Frame rootFrame)
{
    var shell = Container.GetInstance<MainView>();
    shell.SetFrame(rootFrame);
    return shell;
}

protected override Type GetPageType(string pageToken)
{
    var type = Type.GetType(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName.Replace(GetType().FullName, GetType().Namespace + ".Views.{0}View"), pageToken));
    if (type != null)
        return type;
    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("/Prism.Windows/Resources/").GetString("DefaultPageTypeLookupErrorMessage"), pageToken, GetType().Namespace + ".Views"), nameof(pageToken));
}

protected override Task OnInitializeAsync(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    Container.RegisterSingleton(SessionStateService);
    Container.RegisterSingleton(DeviceGestureService);
    Container.RegisterSingleton(NavigationService);
    Container.RegisterSingleton(EventAggregator);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

protected override void ConfigureViewModelLocator()
{
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new 
    SimpleInjectorServiceLocatorAdapter(Container));
}
```

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace incl. all inner exceptions. I bet you'll find the answer right there. Simple injector will probably quit clearly state that a registration for INavigationService is missing.

Comment: @Ric.Net Prism Added new output error information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When application starts, this error come up

In the `MainView.xaml`, you defined the `AutoWireViewModel` property to true. Once this property is set to `True`, the [`ViewModelLocator`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Windows10/Prism.Windows/Mvvm/ViewModelLocator.cs) will try to instantiate the corresponding ViewModel based on a particular convention. Since the names of your View and ViewModel met the convention, when you set this property to true, Prism will help you instantiate the corresponding ViewModel.

Inside `Prism.mvvm` namespace, the [`ViewModelLocationProvider`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Mvvm/ViewModelLocationProvider.cs) class locates the view model for the view that has the `AutoWireViewModelChanged`attached property set to true. And the error is thrown by the following code line of `ViewModelLocationProvider` class:

```
/// <summary>
/// The default view model factory which provides the ViewModel type as a parameter.
/// </summary>
static Func<Type, object> _defaultViewModelFactory = type => Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

> System.MissingMethodException: 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object.'

So it is caused by the [`Activator.CreateInstance(Type)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx) method requires a public constructor, please see `MissingMethodException`.

> If I add a parameterless constructor it works normal.

It seems like this is the correct solution. If you just don't want a  parameterless constructor for the `ViewModel`, you may try instantiate it and set the `DataContext` to the `View` by yourself. If you doubt this is an issue for Prism library maybe you can open a thread [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues).

**Update:**

According to @rubStackOverflow, it was missing `ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewModelFactory((viewMo‌​delType) => Container.GetInstance(viewModelType));` on `OnInitializeAsync` method.

Comment: @sunteen-wu-msft It was missing `ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewModelFactory((viewModelType) => Container.GetInstance(viewModelType));` on `OnInitializeAsync`, please add to your answer.